# RewriteCond when REQUEST_URI do not match htaccess apache2

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, apache2, apache2.4

I have a multilingual wordpress website and want to redirect website of given region to given language,

```
xyz.de --> xyz.de/de/ 
xyz.co.uk --> xyz.co.uk/en/
```

direct access to `xyz.de/de` and `xyz.co.uk/en` are working properly. So there is no problem on wordpress side.

Now, I am trying to change the htaccess file of `xyz.de` and `xyz.co.uk` so that they redirect the website.

Considering xyz.co.uk

I want to add a RewriteCond such that whenever there is no `/en` trailing after `xyz.co.uk` it will automatically add `/en`.

For example `xyz.co.uk/<trailing address>` results in `xyz.co.uk/en/<trailing address>`

So far I have the following code, which somehow doesn't seem to work,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xyz.co.uk/en/$1 [L]
```

The negation of `/en` is not working! I have also tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xyz.co.uk/en/$1 [L]
```

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong? seems like I have gone wrong in writing RegEx and suggest if there is better way to achieve the same, that does not affect the SEO across different domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/en/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]
```

- Make sure to keep this rule as your very first rule in .htaccess.
- Change it to `R=301` once you've tested.